# How to implement Composite Primary Key in Hibernate?

Tags: java, jpa

I have two tables with primary keys questionNumber and assessmentId. I want to use these two to make them composite in two different tables. Is this possible. Should I add something to this to make it work. OR is there another way to implement it. OR should I add question meta data to question and just used the composite key in AnswerKey

```
  Question

        @Entity
        @Getter
        @Setter
        public class Question implements Serializable {

            @Id
            @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
            private int questionId;

            private int questionNumber;

            private String assessmentId;

            private QuestionTypes questionType;

            private String questionText;

            private String questionURL;

            private QuestionStatus questionStatus;

            @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
            @JoinColumn(name = "questionNumber", referencedColumnName = "questionNumber")
            private List<QuestionOption> questionOptions;
           //Constructor
        // Getter and setter
        }

Assessment

@Entity
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"questionList"})
public class Assessment {

    @Id
    private String assessmentId;

    private String assessmentTopic;

    private String assessmentSubTopic;

    private String assessmentLevel;

    private String createdBy;

    private String rating;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "assessmentId", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Question> questionList;

   //Constructor
   //Setter and getter
}


QuestionMetaData



     @Entity
        public class QuestionMetaData {

            @Id
            private QuestionAssessmentKey questionAssessmentKey;

            private String topicName;

            private String subtopicName;

            private QuestionComplexity complexity;

            private String conceptName;
           //Getter and setter
          //Constructor
        }

   AnswerKey



@Entity
public class AnswerKey {

    @Id
    private QuestionAssessmentKey questionAssessmentKey;

    private Character answer;

  //Constructor
// Setter and getter
}


    Key

    @Embeddable
    public class QuestionAssessmentKey implements Serializable {

        private int questionNumber;

        private String assessmentId;
      //Constructor
    //Setter and Getter
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are "derived identities", so your mappings should like this:

```
@Entity
public class Assessment {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private String assessmentId;

    private String assessmentTopic;

    private String assessmentSubTopic;

    private String assessmentLevel;

    private String createdBy;

    private String rating;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "assessment", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Question> questionList;

    // ...
}

@Entity
public class Question implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private QuestionAssessmentKey questionAssessmentKey;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("assessmentId") // maps assessmentId attribute of embedded id
    private Assessment assessment;

    private QuestionTypes questionType;

    private String questionText;

    private String questionURL;

    private QuestionStatus questionStatus;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "questionNumber", referencedColumnName = "questionNumber")
    private List<QuestionOption> questionOptions;

    // ...
}

@Entity
public class QuestionMetaData {

    @EmbeddedId
    private QuestionAssessmentKey questionAssessmentKey;

    private String topicName;

    private String subtopicName;

    private QuestionComplexity complexity;

    private String conceptName;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("assessmentId") // maps assessmentId attribute of embedded id
    private Assessment assessment;

    // ...
}

@Entity
public class AnswerKey {

    @EmbeddedId
    private QuestionAssessmentKey questionAssessmentKey;

    private Character answer;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("assessmentId") // maps assessmentId attribute of embedded id
    private Assessment assessment;

    // ...
}

@Embeddable
public class QuestionAssessmentKey implements Serializable {

    private String assessmentId;

    private int questionNumber;

    // ...
}
```

Comment: In QuestionMetadat and answerkey classes u have added questionId. But shouldnt that be QuestionNumber as my composite key is questionnumber + assessment id. Not question id + assessment id.

Comment: Isnt it possible to leave questionId and have question number as part of the composite key

Comment: Hmmm. Sorry about that. I edited my answer to use `questionNumber`. Maybe that is more helpful?

Comment: Also, I do no understand your model perfectly; but it seems like the primary key for `Question` should be a composite key made up of `assessmentId` and `questionNumber` (i.e. each `Question` belongs to an `Assessment` and has a unique `questionNumber` within that `Assessment`). Does that make sense?

Comment: Yeah u r right. Its better that even that has a composite key. So should i temove questionid completely

Comment: Yes, I think you should remove `questionId`. I have edited my answer again so the code looks something like what I am talking about. I hope it makes sense. :-)